# What am I missing in my mock HttpRequestMessage that is causing an ArgumentNullException in CreateResponse?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions

I have a simple mock `HttRequestMessage` created by

```
    public static HttpRequestMessage FromJson(string uriString, string json = null)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(uriString)
        };

        if (json != null)
        {
            request.Content = new HttpContentJson(json);
        }

        request.Properties.Add("HttpContext", new DefaultHttpContext() {  });


        return request;
    }
```

and when `req.CreateErrorResponse(…)` is run it gives a non-useful exception message

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   provider'

So, what is `provider`?

Comment: @Nkosi I still get the error after trying both answers on there. I think this is something different. Notice that my exception message is different.

Comment: @Nkosi I ran into this same error and came up with a different solution than was outlined in the other answer. The other answers work when the test project targets full framework but doesn't appear to work when the test project targets .NET Core because Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/System.Web.Http (which is where those classes come from) doesn't have a .NET Standard version.

Comment: @KevinSecrist Yes that would make sense given the major differences between the versions. As you mentioned, the linked answer is for full framework.

Comment: @Nkosi Would it be appropriate to reopen this question? I can post the solution I came up with

Comment: @KevinSecrist This question however refers to the full framework. What I would suggest is you do up a new question with the problem you encountered. Making sure to note that it is for .net core. You can make reference back to this and other similar duplicates for the full framework. You can then post you answer as a self answer so that others can benefit from your findings.