# How do I mock/stub HttpRequestMessage in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a function that I'm porting from Azure Functions v1 to v2, and as part of that I've run into an issue updating my unit tests which create a stubbed HttpRequestMessage. Here's the code that works on Functions v1, targeting .NET Framework 4.7

```
public class FunctionExample
{
    [FunctionName(nameof(SomeFunction))]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SomeFunction
    (
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "SomeFunction")]
        HttpRequestMessage request
    )
    {
        var body = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
        {
            return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad job");
        }
        else
        {
            return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Good job");
        }
    }
}
```

And my test code

```
public class FunctionExampleTests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task TestSomeFunction()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost/"),
            Content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

        request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey,
            new HttpConfiguration());

        var response = await FunctionExample.SomeFunction(request);

        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
        Assert.That(content, Is.EqualTo("\"Bad job\""));
    }
}
```

After porting to v2, my function project `csproj` file looks like this. The only differences are that I'm *no longer* targeting full framework, and the addition of the `AzureFunctionsVersion` node.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And this is the `csproj` for my test project after retargeting to .NET Core 2.0

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FunctionExample\FunctionExample.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Previously, I was using the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44447232) to properly stub out HttpRequestMessage but that no longer appears to work.

When I try to compile this, I get the following compilation errors

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'HttpConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   CS0103  The name 'HttpPropertyKeys' does not exist in the current context
```

So if I just remove the line, hoping that the fix is no longer needed

```
request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new HttpConfiguration());
```

Instead I get this error message

> System.InvalidOperationException : The HttpRequestMessage instance is not properly initialized. Use HttpRequestMessageHttpContextExtensions.GetHttpRequestMessage to create an HttpRequestMessage for the current request.

Trying to follow the error message's directions didn't prove fruitful to me, I tried to set the `HttpContext` [like was done in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54965077)

```
request.Properties.Add(nameof(HttpContext), new DefaultHttpContext());
```

But that gave me a different error (same as in the question)

> System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: provider

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Azure Functions is somewhat based on ASP.NET MVC WebApi, which has had some changes for .NET Core. `HttpConfiguration` for example doesn't appear to be available in any packages that target .NET Core/Standard. In order to fix this, I had to install a couple of packages in my **test** project, namely [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/) for `AddMvc()` and [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/) for `.AddWebApiConventions()`, which:

> Provides compatibility in ASP.NET Core MVC with ASP.NET Web API 2 to simplify migration of existing Web API implementations

So I added these to my test project

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim" Version="2.2.0" />
```

and now my test project looks like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FunctionExampleFunction\FunctionExampleFunction.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

To mock the services that the `ArgumentNullException` was implying were missing (which in this case I think are MediaTypeFormatters), I had to essentially bootstrap MVC to get the HttpContext initialized properly.

```
[Test]
public async Task TestSomeFunction()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost/"),
        Content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };

    var services = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddMvc()
        .AddWebApiConventions()
        .Services
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    request.Properties.Add(nameof(HttpContext), new DefaultHttpContext
    {
        RequestServices = services
    });

    var response = await FunctionExample.SomeFunction(request);

    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
    Assert.That(content, Is.EqualTo("\"Bad job\""));
}
```

And that makes the test compile, run, and pass.

Comment: Well put together findings that relate to the more recent versions. Well done.

Comment: Excellent answer! Should each service collection be initialised in each test or can that be shared?

Comment: Thanks! You should be able to share the service collection if you use it as described here. Remember to use a new HttpRequestMessage in each test though.